# SQL Query to return certain values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this SQL Query (I'm working with Access):

```
SELECT 
    [tbl - User List].*, 
    [lnk - UserStatusList].[Employee Status], 
    [tbl - App por region].[region]
FROM 
    (
        -- Left Joining User List with Excepciones on Unique ID
        [tbl - User List] 
        LEFT JOIN [lnk - Excepciones] ON [tbl - User List].[Unique ID] = TRIM([lnk - Excepciones].[Unique ID])
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN [lnk - UserStatusList] ON [tbl - User List].[Unique ID] = [lnk - UserStatusList].[Unique ID SAP HR]
     LEFT JOIN [tbl - App por region] ON [tbl - user list].[resource] = [tbl - App por region].[app]
WHERE 
    (
        [lnk - Excepciones].[Unique ID] Is Null 
        AND [tbl - User List].[Resource status] NOT LIKE "Deregistered" 
        AND (
            ([tbl - User List].Resource) NOT LIKE "FOPAG" 
            AND ([tbl - User List].Resource) NOT LIKE "*_QA" 
            AND ([tbl - User List].Resource) NOT LIKE "*_DEV"  
            AND ([tbl - User List].Resource) NOT LIKE "ADGroup*"
        )
    )
ORDER BY [tbl - User List].[resource];
```

It works fine, returning something like this (there are about 147.000 rows of users):
[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxh54.png)

Regards
I want the query to work like this:

- If there is more than one Unique ID in a Resource, then return just one value according to:

1. If the HR Status is "Active", give me that row, I don't care if there are others with "Inactive" or "Withdrawn" status
2. If there is no HR Status "Active", then give me the "Inactive" one (discard the "Withdrawn")
3. If there is no "Active" or "Inactive", then give me the "Withdrawn"

So, for this example, the query should give me just these values:
[Good query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5jEO.png)

I tried to do it with ChatGPT but I have no success.

Comment: Data should be provided as formatted text table, not image. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Answer (score 1):

Those Status values will alphabetically sort in the same order they are prioritized.

Filtering records based on data in other records can be tricky and usually requires correlated subquery or VBA function. Query would look something like following (using posted query result as source):

```
SELECT *
FROM Query1 WHERE [HR Status] IN(
    SELECT TOP 1 [HR Status] FROM Query1 AS Dupe 
    WHERE Dupe.[Unique ID]=Query1.[Unique ID] 
    AND Dupe.Resource=Query1.Resource ORDER BY [HR Status]);
```

However, in your case, a normal GROUP BY aggregation can produce same output (again, with posted query result as source):

```
SELECT [Unique ID], [Full name], [Contract Type], Resource, [Resource ID], 
Min([HR Status]) AS [MinStatus]
FROM Query1
GROUP BY [Unique ID], [Full name], [Contract Type], Resource, [Resource ID];
```